# Excel formula that combines MATCH, INDEX and OFFSET

Tags: excel

I am having trouble with an Excel-function.

On sheet A I want to get the value of a cell that is located x-columns to the right of cell F2.
X is a variable number and is determined by the value of cell A1. Currently, the value is 5.

```
=(OFFSET(sheetA!F2,0,sheetA!A1))
```

This formula works. However, I want to include this function into a MATCH and INDEX function that is located on another sheet (B).

I know that I can use the following formula to get value of $F$2

```
INDEX(sheetA!F:F,MATCH(sheetB!C4,sheetA!A:A,0))
```

Combining them, results in the following formula:

```
=INDEX((OFFSET(sheetA!F2,0,sheetA!A1)),MATCH(sheetB!C4,sheetA!A:A,0))
```

This formula generates a #REF!-value.

If I evaluate the formula, I see the following steps:

```
=INDEX((OFFSET(sheetA!$F$2,0,5)),MATCH(sheetB!C4,sheetA!A:A,0))
=INDEX((sheetA!$K$2),MATCH(sheetB!C4,sheetA!A:A,0))
=INDEX((sheetA!$K$2),MATCH("BTC",sheetA!A:A,0))
=#REF!
```

*Why do I want to use MATCH and INDEX?*
Because while the values on sheet A are "fixed", the values of sheetB!C4 are floating/variable. Therefore, I need to locate the correct row first. The correct column can be done with the offset-part.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=INDEX((OFFSET(SheetA!F:F,0,SheetA!A1)),MATCH(SheetB!C4,SheetA!A:A,0))
```

Syntax of `INDEX` is

```
INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])
```

where, array is range of cells. When you use `=INDEX((OFFSET(sheetA!F2,0,sheetA!A1)),MATCH(sheetB!C4,sheetA!A:A,0))`, `(OFFSET(sheetA!F2,0,sheetA!A1))` returns `sheetA!$K$2` which is a cell not a range.